# How do I build this grid in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've got a PSD with a grid, the width of the site is:  980px
Each column has a width of 100px, with a spacing of 10px

I'm pretty new to working with grids, and I've tried using a grid generator, however, cant quite find one which works properly to this grid.

It has to be a responsive, to in % instead of px

How do I set this up?

See the grid here:
[image]

Comment: You could use Foundation and not have to reinvent the wheel: http://foundation.zurb.com/

Answer (score 0):

You say each column has to be 100px, but also has to be responsive and use a % value?
I'm confused.

Did you mean like this? 
http://jsfiddle.net/wV9Ug/